# How to Log either of the 2 messages if its corresponding condition is satisfied

Tags: selenium, if-statement, robotframework

My Code looks like :

```
${tempclosed}   ${value}=   Run Keyword And Ignore Error    Element Should Not Be Visible   ${orderonline}

Run Keyword If  '${tempclosed}' == 'TRUE'   log Store is Closed on Zomato Or is Temporarily Closed  Element Should Be Visible   ${overview}

Sleep   3s

Run Keyword Unless  '${tempclosed}' == 'FALSE'  log Store is Open on Zomato
```

"here if ${tempclosed} element is found on GUI i want the message to be logged as "Store is Closed on Zomato Or is Temporarily Closed" and if ${tempclosed} element is not found then log "Store is Open on Zomato", considering the test should continue to pass "

the current output that i get is : it logs the second message "Store is Open on Zomato" in both the cases.

How do I get the first message logged when that element is found ?

Comment: Please take a minute to format the code in your question as code so that it's more easily read. If you aren't sure how to do that, please see the formatting help that is available when editing the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may simply try :

```
${tempclosed}   ${value}=   Run Keyword And Ignore Error    Element Should Not Be Visible   ${orderonline}

Run Keyword If  '${tempclosed}' == 'PASS'   log   Store is Closed on Zomato Or is Temporarily Closed  ELSE IF '${tempclosed}' == 'FAIL'   log   Store is Open on Zomato
```

Answer (score 0):

You are incorrectly using keyword `Run Keyword And Ignore Error` because it's returns because it returns `PASS` or `FAIL`, not `TRUE` or `FALSE`, here is [link](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Ignore%20Error) to documentation.

First `Log` is not executed because condition `'${tempclosed}' == 'TRUE'` is never met, no matter if it's `PASS` or `FAIL`.
Second `Log` is always execute because of the same reason, but different is that you are using `Run Keyword Unless` keyword.

So solution would be to replace `TRUE` and `FALSE` with `PASS` and `FAIL`.

Comment: well i was confused with this part, though i had made separate keywords with the message that i want to log if a particular element is found. Still the condition failed.

Run Keyword And Return If '${tempclosed}' == 'TRUE' ZomatoStoreCLosed
Sleep 5s 
Run Keyword If '${tempclosed}' == 'FALSE' ZomatoStoreopen  -- would this work if i store the message that i want to log in a separate keyword and call RUN KEYWORD IF

Answer (score 0):

```
log Store is Closed on Zomato Or is Temporarily Closed  Element Should Be Visible   ${overview}
```

I think this won't work even if you have correct condition (PASS/FAIL), as there seems to be two keywords and an argument for the latter keyword:
 - No two spaces after Log, or is that `log Store is Closed on Zomato Or is Temporarily Closed` really a keyword?
 - Are you planning to execute `Element Should Be Visible` in an `ELSE` statement? Then it should be ... `log Store is Closed on Zomato Or is Temporarily Closed    ELSE    Element Should Be Visible   ${overview}`

Comment: well i was confused with this part, though i had made separate keywords with the message that i want to log if a particular element is found. Still the condition failed.

Run Keyword And Return If '${tempclosed}' == 'TRUE' ZomatoStoreCLosed
Sleep 5s 
Run Keyword If '${tempclosed}' == 'FALSE' ZomatoStoreopen  -- would this work if i store the message that i want to log in a separate keyword and call RUN KEYWORD IF